# rails + kubernetes pod slow booting time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes

is there any people in here that run rails pod inside kubernetes, just curious how long does it take to boot until http ready to serve the request.

for me it tooks around 20-30 seconds on existing node.
but, when there is no node to accomodate new pod. the karpenter provision new node. and the pod fully ready around 90s in total. waiting for the new node becomes ready.

Note:
i already removed unused Gem, removing unused rails component, using bootsnap to improve my boot time, and reducing docker image by using ruby alpine, but the result not significant. it reduction only 4 seconds. im targeting around 50% reduction. i also profiling my rails boot. but, it seems the profiler result mostly goes to rails/3rd library that i use. so i can't do much on that. im running for API server that still monolith.

My setup:

- ruby '3.0.0'
- gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.2'
- http server running by puma in clustered mode

any helps will be appreciated. Thanks